# IPhone SDK 4 background process for incoming call

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to track (run some code - or invoke function) when the user get an incoming call. 
for example: for every call the user receive I want to save the number, and check something during or before the call is answered (with a background process..)

Until now without the background processing I couldn't find a way to do this. But I'm still not sure it is possible.

Anyone with information about the new sdk 4 can help me?

Comment: Any information about iPhone OS 4 from a developer perspective is under Apple's non-disclosure agreement. Therefore, anyone who has that information can't share it with you (disclose it to you) without breaking their agreement with Apple.

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest joining the developer program to get access to the beta and new APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the published material that would suggest that there's any change. The seven types of multitasking listed were:

1. Background Audio
2. Voice Over IP
3. Location Services
4. Push Notifications
5. Local Notifications
6. Task Completion
7. Fast App Switching

Intercepting normal cell calls doesn't really fit into any of those categories.

Comment: So I guess the answer is no.. It makes me hate Apple. they have too many restrictions for their products. Google is the best.

Comment: Apple takes privacy very seriously and a list of numbers that have called the device is not something Apple wants a third-party app to have access to.

Comment: You asked a question and these people answered it.  Just because you don't like their answers doesn't mean you need to be disrespectful.

Answer (score 2):

You can register for notifications using CTTelephony and your app will NOT terminate while the call is in progress. Control is returned to the app at the conclusion of the call and then you can get the phone number.

All of this is useless for apps to be published in the App Store until Apple approves use of the CTTelephony API.